# Get the commands history from GAP system

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, mathematical-software, gap

I am not sure whether this was asked before, but I didn't find a reference in GAP system documentation on how to print the history of the command line (Ubuntu installation).

For instance:

```
gap> G := Group((1,2)(3,4),(1,2,3));
> irr := Irr(G);
```

How to save or print the list of my previous commands (similar to **history** command on Ubuntu).

Many thanks.

Comment: I suggest you send an inquiry to the [GAP Forum](https://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/Forum/forum.html). There are lots of experts there that can help you.

Comment: You can use LogTo("filename.txt"); to save all subsequent output (including commands you run) to the specified file, if this is what you want. To stop saving, use LogTo(); (i.e. with no argument).

Comment: Works perfectly, many thanks!
Could you please turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three commands that will do all variations of this:

1. `LogTo("filename.txt")` will save all subsequent **input and output** to a file with the specified name.
2. `InputLogTo("filename.txt")` will save all subsequent **input** to a file with the specified name.
3. `OutputLogTo("filename.txt")` will save all subsequent **output** to a file with the specified name.

In all three cases, running the command with no argument will stop the logging. More details can be found [here in the GAP Manual](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap9.html#X79813A6686894960).

Comment: In addition, there are `SaveCommandLineHistory ` and `ReadCommandLineHistory`, if GAP is built with readline support: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap6.html#X7C1F4D04861C1197